# Stop IE8 from opening or downloading a text/plain MIME type

Tags: text, internet-explorer-8, types, mime

I'm dynamically generating a text file in PHP, so it has a .php extension but a text/plain MIME type. All browsers display the file as nicely preformatted text, except IE8.

Googling tells me that they've added security where if the HTTP header content type doesn't match the expected content type (I think based on the extension and some sniffing) then it forces the file to be downloaded. In my case I have to open it, and also give it permission to open the file I just told it open! That's probably a Win7 annoyance though. Serving a static plain text file works fine, of course.

So can I stop IE8 from downloading the file and get it to view it normally? The code has to run on multiple shared hosting environments, so I think I'm stuck with the .php extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your HTTP header:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

It's an IE8 feature to opt-out of its MIME-sniffing.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx)

Comment: Looks promising from the article, but it's not making a difference I'm afraid!

Comment: Is there a reason you have to serve text/plain? Could you just serve HTML and format the text with `<pre></pre>`?

Comment: I take it back, 6 hours later the header magic is working. Must have been the usual over-enthusiastic caching!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can "trick" IE8 into thinking that it is indeed serving up a text file. These 2 lines do it for me and don't involve using non-standardized "X-" headers:

```
Header("Content-Type: text/plain");
Header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"whatever.txt\"");
```